# How can I count the number of times a column has the same value in a sequence?

Tags: google-bigquery, count

I am looking for a solution in BigQuery where I could count the number of times a column has the same value in a sequence. Currently, I have this table and I would like to have a new column that counts how often the value in flow column has occurred in the sequence.

Data :

```
with t as (session_id,page_group,page_name,steps_flow) as values (
(1017911,Home Page,Home Page,1),
(1017911,Site Search,Site Search,2),
(1017911,Range - PIP,Wall shelves,3),
(1017911,Range - PIP,Wall shelves,4),
(1017911,Range - PIP,Wall shelves,5),
(1017911,Range - PIP,Wall shelves,6),
(1017911,Site Search,Site Search,7),
(1017911,Site Search,Site Search,8),
(1017911,Ideas,Ideas,9),
(1017911,Range - PLP,EKTORP series,10),
(1017911,Range - PIP,Sofas,11)
)
```

(new col f0 is the expected output):

[current data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjk2f.png)

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWBIJ.png)
[image]

I am not able to find the right query.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a kind of *gaps and islands* problem and you might consider below

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT(gap, island), COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY island) FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNTIF(gap) OVER w1 AS island FROM (
    SELECT *, page_name <> LAG(page_name) OVER w0 AS gap
      FROM sample_table
    WINDOW w0 AS (PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY steps_flow)
  ) WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY steps_flow)
);

-- Query results

+------------+-------------+---------------+------------+-----+
| session_id | page_group  |   page_name   | steps_flow | f0_ |
+------------+-------------+---------------+------------+-----+
|    1017911 | Home Page   | Home Page     |          1 |   1 |
|    1017911 | Site Search | Site Search   |          2 |   1 |
|    1017911 | Range - PIP | Wall shelves  |          3 |   4 |
|    1017911 | Range - PIP | Wall shelves  |          4 |   4 |
|    1017911 | Range - PIP | Wall shelves  |          5 |   4 |
|    1017911 | Range - PIP | Wall shelves  |          6 |   4 |
|    1017911 | Site Search | Site Search   |          7 |   2 |
|    1017911 | Site Search | Site Search   |          8 |   2 |
|    1017911 | Ideas       | Ideas         |          9 |   1 |
|    1017911 | Range - PLP | EKTORP series |         10 |   1 |
|    1017911 | Range - PIP | Sofas         |         11 |   1 |
+------------+-------------+---------------+------------+-----+
```

You can test the query with below sample data.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT '1017911' session_id, 'Home Page' page_group, 'Home Page' page_name, 1 steps_flow  UNION ALL
  SELECT '1017911', 'Site Search', 'Site Search', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '1017911', 'Range - PIP', 'Wall shelves', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT '1017911', 'Range - PIP', 'Wall shelves', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT '1017911', 'Range - PIP', 'Wall shelves', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT '1017911', 'Range - PIP', 'Wall shelves', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT '1017911', 'Site Search', 'Site Search', 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT '1017911', 'Site Search', 'Site Search', 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT '1017911', 'Ideas', 'Ideas',9 UNION ALL
  SELECT '1017911', 'Range - PLP', 'EKTORP series',10 UNION ALL
  SELECT '1017911', 'Range - PIP', 'Sofas',11 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it very easily by using the **COUNT** function and the **OVER(PARTION BY)** function:

```
SELECT session_id, page_content_group, page1, flow,
   COUNT(page_content_group) OVER(PARTITION BY page_content_group ) AS count_column
FROM your_table
```

(Ps. You would achieve the same result by using the page1 column)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.. i actually dont have code , i am trying partitions but not able to get the desired result .  I have tried your suggestion but in that case , for the search column i am getting output as 3 but ideally in the first search (row2) , i should get 1 and in the next occurrence of search (row 7 and 8), the result should be 2.Row

Comment: But you could create some sample data and then you will see that the code works as you showed in the screenshot you uploaded. Give it a try, and if you cannot find a solution I will upload some sample data and you will see that the results will be similar as your screenshot ;)